# "Overflow-scroll true" not working in ionic application for ios device

Tags: html, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic application and trying to improve performance of the same. While working around, I have found that most of the suggestions are related to scrolling as it is very important functionality and it is suggested that **overflow-scroll="true"** should be used in `ionic-content` tag....

I have used it and ooopss... scrolling in my application stopped.. I am unable to dictate what is happening with this tag?

I am using iPhone6 plus for testing.. am I doing wrong somewhere?

following is my code

```
<ion-content class="content-padding dashboard dashboardContent contentTop" overflow-scroll="true">
     <ion-process-spinner css-class="loadingSpinner" spinner="ios" processing="isProcessingDashboardDetails">
    <section class="panelSection">
      <!-- other UI tags -->
    </section>
    </ion-process-spinner>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic by default uses the Ionic scroll, which simulates the Momentum Scrolling as seen on the iOS devices, by adding the `overflow-scroll=true` attribute, you are basically forcing **this** particular `ion-content` to use the native scrolling (if you want a global effect check out [this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/).

However if I were you I would check if my css classes are affecting the style of the element!

EDIT: 4 years have passed since I wrote this answer and Ionic has matured a lot since then. I would invite anyone to have a look at [this other link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content) as I think the API changed too much for the previous answer to still be relevant.

Comment: ok ... thanks @Luke... I'll check this out...and let you know!!

Comment: link is dead please update or summarize the solution

Comment: I don't think summarising the solution would help anymore since Ionic has made huge changes in 4 years. All I can do is point to the new documentation - find the updated answer ;-)